# Remove rows from dataframe based on index

Tags: python

I got a list containing row indexes to delete. The list contains duplicates so to lighten the burden I tried to remove duplicate entries:

```
invalid_rows = list(dict.fromkeys(invalid_rows))
```

Returning:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Okey, well let's try with duplicate values just to see if I can remove the rows:

```
df = df.drop(index=invalid_rows)
```

Returning the same error code. What's the problem with the list? I tried to google but I can't seem to find the error.

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what `invalid_rows` looks like. You should provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Did you consider using https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates ?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that `invalid_rows` is not a `list`, it is actually a `nested list`. `fromkeys` method tries to use elements of that list as keys for dictionary, but since its elements (at least one of them) are not hashable type, it raises an error.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to remove duplicates from a list would be:

```
invalid_rows = list(set(invalid_rows))
```

This of course assumes invalid_rows is a list of hashable items

Comment: The error already says that `invalid_rows` contains an unhashable type.

Comment: Thanks, it seem like my list is nested for some reason. Will try to figure it out.